Random graph theory for an evolving graph (fixed finite vertices, edges added + removed)
Is it possible to model an evolving graph (dynamic graph) using random graph theory, where the number of vertices of the model are fixed, but a set of edges are deleted and inserted at every time step. I have seen percolation theory looks at removal of edges and the standard random graph theory looks at edges in preferential attachment. But are there any interesting studies where certain interesting graph properties (like cycles, giant CCs etc) appear and disapear (phase transitions) or stay invariant? Just wondering what would be a good assumption to make about the underlying evolving dynamic and how to model it? Any references you can share would greatly help!

How about this? https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.07570
